Formulas not updating after Excel File updated by Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB from SQLServer
I'm attempting to programatically produce excel files from a sql job through the JET driver:
I am inserting data into the Data tab, then setting the rate denominators on the Summary Tab.
declare @someparam varchar(255) = 'Foo'
    declare @filename varchar(512) 
    declare @path varchar(2000)
    declare @template varchar(2000)
    declare @cmd varchar(4000)
    declare @sql varchar(4000)

        set @filename  =concat('Some Doc - ',@someparam,' - ',convert(varchar,getdate(),112),'.xlsx')
        set @path   = '\\path\to\file'
        set @template   = '\\path\to\template.xlsx'
        set @cmd = 'copy /Y "'+@template+'" "'+@path+'\'+@filename+'"'  

        exec xp_cmdshell @cmd 
 
        set @sql = 'insert into OPENROWSET( ''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
                                    ''Excel 12.0;Database='+@path+'\'+@filename+';'',
                                    ''Select * From [Data$]''
                                  )select * from ##some_data
                                  where param = '''+@someparam+''' order by id' 


        exec xp_cmdshell @cmd 
        exec (@sql)

        set @sql = 'update q set 
                        [Quarter] = a.qtr ,  
                        [Census] = a.census , 
                        [MMO] = a.mmo 
                    from (select * from  OPENROWSET( ''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
                                    ''Excel 12.0;Database='+@path+'\'+@filename+';'',
                                    ''Select * From [Quarterly$A2:E7]''
                                  ) )    Q 
                                  JOIN ##quarters a on Q.[ID] = a.[id] 
                                  where param = '''+@someparam+'''' 

        exec (@sql)

Formulas on the summary tab calculates values based on sumifs. However, the formulas are not updating when I open the file (ie values remain values from the template file, until I either double click on the Quarter column). Formulas are set to Automatic. I am assuming that since I am inserting data using the JET driver, some kind of "changed" flag is not being set to trigger formula evaluation? Is there a way that I force excel to recalculate the formulas?
I am aware that pivot tables can be set to calculate when open, but for this specific case that is not an option.


Excel isn't recognizing that the data has changed, so it doesn't automatically recalculate the formulas.
Options to force Excel to recalculate the formulas:

VBA Macro: You can create a macro that forces recalculation when the workbook is opened.
vba
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.CalculateFull
End Sub

Save this macro in the ThisWorkbook module of your Excel file. This will force a full recalculation of all formulas when the workbook is opened.

Use Calculate in SQL: If you prefer to keep everything within your SQL job, you can use a simple EXECUTE command after your data insertion to trigger the recalculation.
sql
set @sql = 'EXECUTE Excel.Application.CalculateFullRebuild'
exec (@sql)

This method is more of a workaround, and it may not work in all environments.

Refresh the Data: If you're using Excel with external data connections, ensure that you have the "Refresh data when opening the file" option enabled.
Go to Data > Connections > Properties.
Check the box for "Refresh data when opening the file".

Programmatically Refresh Excel Data Connections:
Another approach can involve a script that refreshes all data connections when the workbook is opened.
vba
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
    For Each conn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    conn.Refresh
    Next conn
    Application.CalculateFull
End Sub



While these methods can help trigger recalculations, it’s essential to test them to find the one that best fits your workflow.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
